# VisualBrush no longer works for Windows 8 Metro Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, microsoft-metro

I'm now developing an app with reflect effect. I tried to assign a VisualBrush to Rectangle.Fill as:

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
   <VisualBrush Opacity="0.75" Stretch="None" Visual="{Binding ElementName=ReflectedVisual}">
   </VisualBrush> 
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

And VS reports VisualBrush doesn't exist in my xml namespace. I manually added it to the XAML file using:

> xmlns:fx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"

And added the reference DLL as well. However, now VS says that I cannot assign a VisualBrush to a property of class Brush.

This seemed weird to me, as I recalled the same code worked well on Vista. Does anyone know if there's anything I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Metro has little to do with Vista.  You'll have to work with the brush classes that are available in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Media namespace.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.aspx

Comment: You might want to vote for it here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3138694-support-for-visualbrush-in-winrt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metro apps do not have the same set of XAML brushes, resources and elements available as in WPF.

A work-around would have been to use a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) and use the Render method to draw the element to the bitmap. Unfortunately [the current version does not support the Render method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/65a6870d-1412-4701-ae12-258ed2b45452).