# WinRT control to render XAML UIElement

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am porting a WPF app into WinRT. The old app had a part where it would take something like an Image, MediaElement, a Xaml Page, etc; cast it as a **UIElement**; and then the recieving class would use **VisualBrush** to render it onto a button.

Unfortunately WinRT has no VisualBrush. I've tried setting content to UIElement etc. I also read about **RenderTargetBitmap**, however I don't think it would work since I also have video content.

Is there any way to make a control that accepts a UIElement and renders it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VisualBrush no longer works for Windows 8 Metro Apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044066/visualbrush-no-longer-works-for-windows-8-metro-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want achieve, you can just set your UIElement in the [Button.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=win.10).aspx) property.

The [Button.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=win.10).aspx) property can accept any UIElement.

For example, you can do the following:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page ...>
<StackPanel  ...>
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="200" Height="200"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >

        <Button.Content>
            <local:Page2 />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Page2.xaml

```
<Page...>
    <Grid ...>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Content="Click Me" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Or from the code behind:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        myButton.Content    = new Page2();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that.. But the uielements passed from the upper class already had that class as the parent. VisualBrush copied the UIElement, so it worked, but I couldn't add the element directly. Overall it was very messy code. Started over.